# Reconfigure dataframe for scatterplot

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I have a dataframe with days as the column header and id as the row header with the count of observations in each cell. I need to restructure the data so it can be used to create a scatterplot.

example data:

```
    day1  day2  day3  day4
ID1 1      3     4     1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions here on SO and what you can do to provide a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). In short, please show us reproducible sample data, a code attempt, and where your code failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a few lines to your example data

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

df <- read.table(text = 
"day1  day2  day3  day4
ID1 1      3     4     1
ID2 2      4     1     3
ID3 1      1     3     4", header = TRUE)

df %>%
  as.matrix %>%
  reshape2::melt(value.name = "count") -> new_df

   Var1 Var2 count
1   ID1 day1     1
2   ID2 day1     2
3   ID3 day1     1
4   ID1 day2     3
5   ID2 day2     4
6   ID3 day2     1
7   ID1 day3     4
8   ID2 day3     1
9   ID3 day3     3
10  ID1 day4     1
11  ID2 day4     3
12  ID3 day4     4
```

Now you can use it for a plot, grouped by `ID` .

```
  ggplot(data = new_df) +
  geom_jitter(aes(x = Var2, y = count, color = Var1), width = 0.2, height = 0.2) + 
  xlab("day")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: you could then accept the answer, so others see what worked for you and you get reputation. :-)

Comment: Sorry! I have accepted. Obviously very new to this site.